# Create a while loop, for tables, in php

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm constructing a site for sell products, i have a table to show products that's like a "square" type of table with **price**,**image**,**information** and **buy button**.

I'm new to this type of code, and i couldn't understand how to do it works. i have here an [example](http://loja.slbenfica.pt/Fam%C3%ADlias/Roupa/tabid/606/Family/1/Roupa.aspx) of what i want. I know that it uses AJAX, but i just want a code/explanation to be able to make that type os "squares" table **with** the products that i have in my *MySQL DataBase*, so that as i add more pruducts it automatacly and another "square".

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    //Conection to DataBase//
    $link=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','produtos');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    exit("falhou a conexão ao mysql:".mysqli_connect_error());

    //Codification Type//
    mysqli_query($link,"set names utf8");

    //Select from DataBase//
    $query="Select * FROM fornos";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if (!$result)
        exit("Error in query SELECT: " . mysqli_error($link));
    $fornos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $imagem = $fornos['file'];
    $preco = $fornos['preco'];

    // Termina a ligação à Base de Dados
    mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Here is my table location:

```
<table id="tabela1">
                    <?php
                        while ($fornos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                        {
                            echo"<tr>";
                            echo"<td class='products_td'> $preco </td>";
                            echo"</tr>";
                            echo"<tr>";
                                echo"<td class='products_td'><img class='img_product' src='images/fornos/$imagem'></td>";
                            echo"</tr>";
                            echo"<tr>";
                                echo"<td class='products_td'>Informações</td>";
                            echo"</tr>";
                            echo"<tr>";
                                echo"<td class='products_td_buy'>Comprar</td>";
                            echo"</tr>";

                        }
                    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tr means table row. You are adding a new row for every detail of each item. You want to use a basic modulus operator to create a new row every 4th item. See here:

```
<?php
    $query="Select * FROM fornos";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if (!$result)
        exit("Error in query SELECT: " . mysqli_error($link));
?>
<table id="tabela1">
   <tr>
   <?php
   $i = 0;
   while ($fornos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
      if($i > 0  && $i % 4 == 0): 
      /* this line above is what creates a new row every 4th. */
      ?>
      </tr><tr>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <td class='products_td'>
        <?php echo $fornos['preco']; ?><br>
        <img class='img_product' src='images/fornos/<?php echo $fornos['file']; ?>'><br>
        Informações<br>
        Comprar
      </td>

    $i ++; endwhile; ?>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This is a basic idea.

Comment: `$fornos`is a variable for "fornos"(my table name) `$preco` is the price variable

Comment: Ok so with $fornos['preco'] replacing what you have, and the image being treated the same, this should get you close to where you need to be.